# How to change main screen layout?

Tags: git, git-extensions

When I look at the GUI apps for Git at https://www.git-scm.com/downloads/guis , I can see for the picture of GitExtensions that the commit details subwindow is to the right of the commit history subwindow.

But I can't do that with my copy of GitExtensions that I just installed today. I found no way to change the layout, with the only layout being the commit history subwindow at the top and all the detail subwindows at the bottom.

How can I change the layout like in that picture in the Git GUI page (and do even more changes if possible!) so I can better use the massively underused screen space on my big wide monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the `Settings` form. Choose in the tree `Detailed` > `Browse repository window`.

You have to check the option `Show the revision details next to the revision list`.

It requires a recent version of GitExtensions (I think at least the 2.50).

I have asked for a more visible option n the `view` menu but it was declined...

Comment: Alright thanks! I had also tried to drag and drop the tabs hoping to be able to dock 'em anywhere but alas!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case where this particular setting is missing from the UI, you can look for the "GitExtensions.settings" file (in e.g. AppData\Roaming\GitExtensions\GitExtensions) and add the following key (or modify accordingly if already present):

```
  <item>
    <key>
      <string>Detailed.CommitInfoPosition</string>
    </key>
    <value>
      <string>RightwardFromList</string>
    </value>
  </item>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what worked for me. That "Show the revision details next to the revision list" option isn't in the UI any more as far as I can tell. I'm using GitExtensions 4.1.